# Zlib won't decompress python 2.7

Tags: python, compression

I am trying to move data from a server to a client via socket.
I try to compress data from the server and send it to the socket,
but when I try to decompress in the client I get this error:

```
zlib.error: Error -5 while decompressing data: incomplete or truncated stream
```

I think I know why, but I don't get why it happens.
Maybe it's because I try to decompress "Uncompressed" data,
because if the client got data it doesn't know if the data is compressed or not and trying to compress it now causes the error.
Maybe I'm completely wrong, but I don't know how to fix it, I need your help.

Client: gets the data (which is a string representing an image)

```
def room_client(port,ip):
roomC = socket.socket()
roomC.connect((ip, port))


while True:
    print 'in while of client server'
    #recv pict
    #display
    #send ack

    img = ""
    size = roomC.recv(1024)
    roomC.sendall(size)

    while len(img) < int(size):
        data = roomC.recv(1024)
        img += data

    roomC.send("ACK")
    to_pic = img.split('@')[0]
    print to_pic
    scrn = open("monitor_serv.png", "wb")
    scrn.write(zlib.decompress(to_pic))
    scrn.close()
```

Server: sending the image(screenshot)

```
def room_server(port):
#sends pictures
print 'in room_server '
roomS = socket.socket()
roomS.bind(('0.0.0.0',port))
roomS.listen(1)

client, addr = roomS.accept()




while True:
    print 'in while of room server'
    # take picture
    # send picture
    # recv ack

    flag = True
    img1 = ImageGrab.grab()
    send = zlib.compress(img1.tobytes())
    size = img1.size

    send = send + "@" + str(size[0]) + "@"+ str(size[1]) + "@0@0"
    client.sendall(str(len(send)))
    print "0"
    f = client.recv(1024)
    print "A ", f
    client.sendall(send)
    g = client.recv(1024)
    print "C ", g
    while True:
        if flag:
            flag = False
            img2 = ImageGrab.grab()
            coordinates = equal(img1, img2)
            cropped_image = img2.crop(coordinates)

        else:
            flag = True
            img1 = ImageGrab.grab()
            coordinates = equal(img1, img2)
            cropped_image = img1.crop(coordinates)

        if coordinates is not None:
            size = cropped_image.size
            send = zlib.compress(cropped_image.tobytes())
            try:
                send = send + "@" + str(size[0]) + "@" + \
                str(size[1]) + "@" + str(coordinates[0]) + "@" + str(coordinates[1])

                client.sendall(str(len(send)))
                client.recv(1024)

                client.sendall(send)
                client.recv(1024)
            except:
                break
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Without seeing any of your code, it's hard to know what's wrong.

Comment: _I need your help_ Showing us the code would be a great start.

Comment: But I can make a wild guess: Your code is relying on the fact that every `recv` on the client gets exactly one `send` from the server, and [this isn't the way TCP works](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/sockets-are-byte-streams-not-message.html), so you often end up with just part of a compressed message, so when you try to decompress that, you get an error that says you've got a truncated stream.

Comment: Also, if I understand you, what you think is going on is that, when you ask to decompress data that isn't compressed, it first tries to compress the data, similar to the way calling `decode` on an already-decoded `unicode` does? If so, that's not what's happening. That 2.x design flaw really only applies to `str`/`unicode`; they didn't reproduce it all over the stdlib.

Comment: Added the server + client

Comment: Thanks for adding the code! From a quick glance, it looks like you have tried to design a messaging protocol, and implement all the stuff like reading in a loop until you have exactly one message, but you haven't got it quite right. There's no delimiters anywhere; you try to read up to 1k instead of up to `min(1024, int(size)-len(img))`, etc. So you may still have data that's truncated at the start or end. Have you tried printing it out or saving it to a file as-is to compare that what you're receiving is exactly what you expect?

Comment: I actually printed what I've got and it does look like a compressed data, but python won't decompress it. :(

Comment: Meanwhile, this looks suspicious: `to_pic = img.split('@')[0]`. What happens if there's an `@` in the compressed data, as there will be the vast majority of the time? (If any of the random-ish bytes happens to be 64.)

Comment: I don't mean "look like a compressed data", I mean "look like exactly the same compressed data you sent from the other side".

Comment: You're right i'll change that right now! but python will still pop an error up

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167490/discussion-between-our-and-abarnert).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the server, you're sending this:

```
send = zlib.compress(img1.tobytes())
size = img1.size

send = send + "@" + str(size[0]) + "@"+ str(size[1]) + "@0@0"
```

On the client, you're parsing it like this:

```
to_pic = img.split('@')[0]
print to_pic
scrn = open("monitor_serv.png", "wb")
scrn.write(zlib.decompress(to_pic))
```

There's going to be a `@` byte in almost all arbitrary compressed files. So your `to_pic` is going to be truncated at the first one. Which means `zlib` will almost always give you an error saying you've given it a truncated stream.

You need to come up with some other way to frame the data. Some options:

- Instead of sending `data@width@height@0@0` prefixed by the byte length of that string, you could send just `data` prefixed by its byte length, width, and height.
- If you want to use `@` as a delimiter, you could escape any `@` bytes inside the actual image data, and then unescape on the other side. For example, you could `replace('@', '@@')`, and then `re.split` on the first single `@` sign, and then `replace('@@', '@')`.
- If you `rsplit` to pull off the last four `@`s instead of `split` to pull off the first one… it's a bit hacky, but it would work here, because none of the other fields could ever have an `@` in them, just the compressed image data field.

---

There are other issues with the protocol framing that you need to rethink, but they're all things that, when you're sending smallish files over localhost sockets, will only occasionally come up; this is the only one that's almost bound to come up almost every time. Unfortunately, that doesn't mean you don't need to fix the other ones; it just means they'll be harder to debug.

---

Meanwhile, there's another flaw in your design:

What you get back from `ImageGrab.grab()` (even before cropping) isn't a PNG image, it's raw PIL/Pillow `Image` data. You compress that on the server, uncompress it on the client, and save those bytes as a PNG file. You can't do that.

One option is to use Pillow on the client as well: create an `Image` object from the decompressed bytes, then tell it to save itself to a PNG file.

Another option is to have the server export to bytes in PNG format instead of giving you the raw bytes. There are two big advantages to this version: No need for PIL installed on the client side, and PNG data is already compressed so you can scrap all your zlib stuff and write much simpler code.

Comment: Yes but I can't open a new Image using PIL image.... and how do I write data to it??

Comment: @OUR You don't _open_ a new image, you _create_ it, with [one of the other constructors](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#constructing-images), probably `Image.frombytes`. (Because that's defined to exactly match the `tobytes` you're using on the other side, and because then you don't have to write data into it afterward, you just pass it in at creation time.)